# Mute Gmail notifiations

Tags: android, notifications, gmail

On my Android device (Samsung Galaxy S8; Android 8.0.0) I have set up [Gmail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm) with both my work account and my private account.

How can I disable the notifications for the work account outside working hours, and how can I disable the notifications for the private account during working hours?

Comment: Well it depends on how you solve the problem I guess.